# Where should WordPress custom page template be placed?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am just asking about custom page template:

If I put it in the subfolder it will work or it should be placed in the root directory.

For example, I created a template named `custom-page-awesome.php` and placed it in **nytemplate** directory.

Please let me know that it's automatically detected when I edit some page or need to include using custom code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress recognizes the subfolder '/page-templates/'. Therefore, it’s a good idea to store your **global** page templates in this folder to help keep them organized.: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Comment: As I checked that it's working, it's not mandatory that what is subfolder name, why it's working I don't know, I have checked using changing the folder name and it's working.. please explain why it's working

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Can you be a little clearer? Are you saying that it is working in your subfolder - `/nytemplate/`?

Comment: Yes, exactly and if I change the name of folder anything, like my-folder, custom-folder, etc then also it's working. it's not necessary folder name should be  '/page-templates/'. can you please tell why it's working

Comment: I think I read somewhere also that you can name the subfolder whatever you like. It just has to be a 'direct' subfolder of the theme root... I think it's just that 'page-templates' is just the recommended naming for templates to be stored in as it makes more sense to most people.

Answer (score 0):

I believe WordPress does not recognize template files that are not in the root directory of the theme. That is unless you use the following function `get_template_part( 'your-template-file' );`

more about that here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this commented line on top of your template php file in the root of the theme folder. It will display the template in the dropdown menu of pages in wordpress backoffice :

Comment: /*
Template Name: template-name
*/

Comment: Yes, I have added commented line on top. /* Template Name: My Awesome Custom Page* and the file is placed on root theme, and it's working, Will this work if I will place in subdirectory, or a specific name should be